# Bootstrap - div over div slideup

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

I can't get my head around this one: I'm creating a mobile webapp with bootstrap. So what I have is a container with a navbar, some divs and again a pill-nav below:

```
<div class="container">
<!-- top navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <!-- ... -->
    </nav>

    <div class="tab-content">

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active fade in" id="map-panel">
            <div id="map"></div>


            <div class="container-fluid" id="teaser-container">
                <div class="row" id="teaser-slideup-button">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <a role="button" href="#teaser-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="teaser-header">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">Teaser header</div>
                </div>

                <div id="teaser-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div style="height: 160px" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <!-- ... -->
    </nav>

</div>
```

What I want to do is let the #teaser-container slide over the #map from below. Basically

```
$('#teaser-slideup-button').on('click', function (e) {

     $('#teaser-container').animate({
            'bottom': '0px'
     });

});
```

Some relevant CSS:

```
#teaser-container {
    z-index:1000; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#map-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

What happens, though, is that the div just appears and seemingly the animation takes place afterwards, scrolling the map div upwards. I've created a JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/jrubisch/hvpjrwrq/

This should not be so hard, I guess, but I'm sort of confused here... I'd be happy to provide more details if required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of solved it by re-grouping the markup:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="teaser-container">

    <div class="teaser-inner">
        <div class="row" id="teaser-slideup-button">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <a role="button" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="teaser-header">
            <div class="col-xs-12">Teaser Header</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="teaser-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div style="height: 160px" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

using `position:relative` on the parent and `position:absolute`on the child:

```
#map-panel {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#teaser-container {
    z-index:1000; 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height:40px;
    overflow: hidden;     
}
```

and animating the height property (basically what $.slideUp does)

```
$('#teaser-container').animate({
    'height': '260px'
}, 500);
```

if somebody knows a more elegant solution, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help, looks and seems to operate in a similar fashion but uses buttons and accordion.

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-up").removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-down").removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom .col-md-6 {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom .btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom .panel-group,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a> 
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <div class="btn btn-warning" id="lowerOpen" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua
          put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Some</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i> Controls</div>
  </div>
</div>
```